# While using JTable , how is it possible to have multiple header rows in multiple rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In JTable is it possible to have headers which can have multiple headers for the same column?

I have seen some of the posts but the code is pretty old and is not working properly. Can any one help on where i can find some examples or understand about JTable support for multiple headers?

[image: Multi row header]

like:

```
col1|    Column2  |   column 3  | Column 4
    |col2-1|col2-2|col3-1|col3-2|
```

Comment: 2-1 specifies that this is under the second col and it has 2 parts 1 and 2 under it .

Comment: Guys please i need help on this :( please replay back

Comment: thanks kleopatra for editing :)

Comment: [Link to SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665397/jtable-multiple-header-rows) from @RaviBagul