# How do I change the model of a JTable

Tags: java, jtable

I'm trying to create a java program that I need a table that looks kind of like this

[image]

I just have no clue on how to do this.

If anyone can help please leave an answer below

Comment: Here's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665397/jtable-multiple-header-rows) and a [resource](http://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/JTableExamples7.html). Good luck, you'll need it...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html should give you all the information you need.

Comment: Here is an example http://esus.com/creating-jtable-nested-headers/